# Alternative to `any_of()` that works with NSE?

Tags: r, dplyr

In a function, I sometimes need to select a variable only if it exists.

For this, the function `dplyr::any_of()` is perfect, but it only works with standard evaluation, taking a character vector as input.

I'm looking for an alternative that would work as a replacement in the following example that feels very hacky:

```r
library(tidyverse) 
library(rlang)
f = function(data, x1, x2, gp){
  gpname =  as_label(enquo(gp))
  data %>%
    select(x1={{x1}}, x2={{x2}}, gp=any_of(gpname)) %>% 
    names()
}

iris %>% f(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Species)
#> [1] "x1" "x2" "gp"
iris %>% f(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)
#> [1] "x1" "x2"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-15 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The function should run with or without `Species`, as in my reprex, but it would make sense that it throws an error if querying an unknown column (unlike in my reprex)

Comment: how would you use non-standard evaluation if the column might not exist? I have no idea what your function f is supposed to do.

Comment: My assumption is that OP wants to do something like `iris |> f(Species, Sepal.Length, foo)` and not have an error.

Comment: FWIW, I don’t see anything wrong with your initial approach. I would tweak to `as_name(ensym(gp))`, but the general idea seems sound.

Comment: @GregorThomas Actually, as I said in my first sentence, the real goal is more to be able to not specify `gp` than to be able to query unexisting columns. I added that in the text.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Would you have an example of a "non-syntactic column name"?

Comment: @DanChaltiel Sure: `a+b`, or `a b`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not sure why I would ever want to do such a thing, but AFAICT the result is exactly what I'd expect: it selects nothing. Would you mind explaining how `as_label()` is wrong here? Especially since @Zephryl's suggestion is not working.

Comment: @DanChaltiel It’s fairly common in data.frame column names, especially when imported from speadsheets using ‘readr’. — However, `as_label()` actually works correctly with non-syntactic names — I made a mistake when testing, and erroneously thought it created redundant quotes around the generated name.

Comment: The downside of `as_label()` compared to `as_name()` is that the former works with arbitrary expressions, which may cause unexpected behaviour. `as_name()` will dutifully report an error when a non-name language is passed to your function. This is generally desirable, but it requires extra handling if you want to allow omitting the argument. However, note that your current code has unexpected behaviour if the data has a column named `<empty>`, because omitting `gp` will return that column!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257187/discussion-between-dan-chaltiel-and-konrad-rudolph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your last statement about wanting errors for requesting an absent variable, it seems its not really an any_of type situation; erroring when asking for impossible columns is commonplace, it looks like you simply want an additional column name to be itself optionally passed in, i.e. a skipabble param.

This is achievable by simply passing default null for the 3rd position.
ie.

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(rlang)
f2 = function(data, x1, x2,x3=NULL){
  data |>
    select({{x1}},
           {{x2}},
           {{x3}}) |> 
    names()
}

iris |> f2(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Species)
iris |> f2(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)
iris |> f2(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,abc)
```

we could generalise and take any number of positions and try to get them with dots.

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(rlang)
f = function(data, x1, x2,...){
  data |>
    select({{x1}},
           {{x2}},
           !!!rlang::enquos(...)) |> 
    names()
}


#runs fine with a variable that is present
iris |> f(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Species)
#  "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Species" 

#its optional and can be left out 
iris |> f(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)
#  "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  

# trying an absent variable correctly errors
iris |> f(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,SpeciesX)
# Error in `select()`:
#   ! Can't select columns that don't exist.
# ✖ Column `SpeciesX` doesn't exist.
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Ohhh how could I not see that NULL would do the trick, thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

One approach would be to use `tidyselect::eval_select(strict=FALSE)` to create a named vector passed to `select()`.  Setting the `strict` argument to false allows failed selections to be ignored. You still need to wrap the selection with `any_of()` when passing an external vector (or you could avoid this and call `eval_select()` inside `select()` without creating an external vector first):

```
library(tidyselect)
library(dplyr)

f <- function(data, x1, x2, gp){
  vars <- eval_select(expr(c(x1 = {{x1}}, x2 = {{x2}}, {{gp}})), data, strict = FALSE)
  data %>%
    select(any_of(vars)) %>%
    names()
}
iris %>% f(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species)
[1] "x1"      "x2"      "Species"

iris %>% f(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, foo)
[1] "x1" "x2"
```